# How do I use the signal in one class to call a function in another in PyQt5?

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5

I want to create a button in my PyQt5 app, which would change the window title name to a new value.

I tried to make a custom function in class PushButton(QPushButton) which would tell MainWindow to setWindowTitle to a new name. Then I connected the .clicked signal within PushButton class to that function, however, whenever I press the button the application crashes.

I am kind of new, so if I got any class/function relationship wrong, please correct me.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> windowTitle : QString
>
> This property holds the window title (caption)
>
> This property only makes sense for top-level widgets, such as windows and dialogs. If no caption has been set, the title is based of the windowFilePath. If neither of these is set, then the title is an empty string.
>
> `setWindowTitle(const QString &)`

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QPushButton, QWidget, QLineEdit, QApplication)


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Change the window title name')
        self.resize(300, 150)        

        self.lineEdit = QLineEdit(self)
        self.lineEdit.move(30, 65)

        button = QPushButton("Button", self)
        button.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)
        button.move(190, 65)
        
    def onClicked(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.lineEdit.text())                 # <---


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]